# TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not Text con PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, pysimplegui

Estoy intentando hacer una base de datos con postgreSQL y PySimpleGui, la cosa es que al querer hacer una tabla que muestre todos los datos que hay guardados me da el error de "TypeError
list indices must be integers or slices, not Text", llevo varias horas tratando de investigar como solucionarlo pero ninguna de las soluciones que he visto me sirven, y quisiera pedirles su ayuda, aqui esta el codigo con el que estoy trabajando

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import psycopg2 

conexion1 = psycopg2.connect(database="contacts", user="postgres", password="abc123")
cursor1 = conexion1.cursor()

cursor1.execute("select id, nombre, edad, estatura, genero, direccion from contactos")
data = cursor1.fetchall()
print(data)
print(type(data))
header_list = {"Id":[], "Nombre":[], "Edad":[], "Estatura":[], "Genero":[], "Direccion":[]}

layout2 = [[sg.Text("Lista de todos los datos almacenados")],
            [sg.Table(values=data,
            display_row_numbers=False, 
            auto_size_columns=True)]
            [sg.VPush()],
            [sg.Push(), sg.CloseButton("Atras")]]
window2  = sg.Window("Consultar datos", layout2, size=(720,300), resizable=True)
while True:
    event, values = window2.read()
    if event == "Atras" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea da ese error? ¿Puedes publicar el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: Se te olvidó poner una coma al final de la linea `auto_size_columns=True)]`. Como no hay una coma, Python cree que estás haciendo slicing(ej [1:-1]) a la lista anterior.

Comment: Ya lo corregí pero ahora me da este error "Exception has occurred: TypeError
object of type 'int' has no len()
  File "D:\Proyectos Python\tablepostgre.py", line 21, in <module>
    event, values = window2.read()", sabras a que se debe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes definir el `header_list` como una lista `header_list = ["Id", "Nombre", "Edad", "Estatura" "Genero", "Direccion"]` y pasarlo como parámetro en el `sg.Table`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import psycopg2 

conexion1 = psycopg2.connect(database="contacts", user="postgres", password="abc123")
cursor1 = conexion1.cursor()

cursor1.execute("select id, nombre, edad, estatura, genero, direccion from contactos")
data = cursor1.fetchall()
print(data)
print(type(data))
header_list = ["Id", "Nombre", "Edad", "Estatura" "Genero", "Direccion"]

layout2 = [[sg.Text("Lista de todos los datos almacenados")],
            [sg.Table(values=data,headings=header_list,
            display_row_numbers=False, 
            auto_size_columns=True)],
            [sg.VPush()],
            [sg.Push(), sg.CloseButton("Atras")]]
window2  = sg.Window("Consultar datos", layout2, size=(720,300), resizable=True)
while True:
    event, values = window2.read()
    if event == "Atras" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
```